# Advice for API DOM

Tags: javascript, json, dom

I have a server with virtual machine and access to it. I would like to create an API on my machine which access a json file on the server. What are my options, steps to do so? I am talking about simple table which can be extracted read/write from 20 machines.

Comment: You should look into using Express.js. This would be a very basic use case for that.

Comment: [how to create rest api](https://www.google.com.sg/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enSG788SG788&ei=288LW5eLKJab9QORhbDIAQ&q=how+to+create+res+api+&oq=how+to+create+rest+api+&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l10.70456.71789.0.73251.10.8.0.2.2.0.73.335.8.8.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.10.341...35i39k1j0i67k1j0i20i263k1.0.yjbSxH9ToM4) Google it and it will give you alot of ways to create an API in server, personally recommend [Node.js](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_restful_api.htm) since you have no mention language or techs to do with